# Scipy Weave: Export vector

Tags: python, c++, numpy, scipy

I want to use scipy-weave to compute an array whose length depends on the data.  Lets take a simplified version of the problem, taking a cumulative sum until a given threshold is reached:

```
from scipy.weave import inline
import numpy as np


def cumsum_until(arr, limit):

    n = len(arr)
    code = '''
    py::list ret;
    float sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        sum += arr[i];
        if (sum < limit)
            ret.append(sum);
        else
            break;
    }
    return_val = ret;
    '''
    R = inline(code,['arr', 'limit', 'n'])
    print R


print cumsum_until(arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5]), limit = 11)
```

[1.0, 3.0, 6.0, 10.0]

Now, doing it with python lists is not efficient - I could do this faster in pure python*.  It seems the appropriate c-structure to use is std::vector, but I can't figure out how to export the final product back into python.  Does anyone know how to do this efficiently?

*Edit: Or so I thought... it seems that building a list in weave is actually 3-4x faster than doing it in python.  But still, I expect a much larger increase by using a pure C++ structure.

Comment: How about a NumPy solution - `arr_cs = arr.cumsum(); 
ret = arr_cs[arr_cs < limit]`?

Comment: In the case of this simplified problem, it works, but the real problem is one where you can't readily determine the maximum length of the list in advance.